# How exactly does the Kreck-Stolz description of elliptic homology match the one by Totaro?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, fibre-bundles, elliptic-cohomology

In

*Kreck, Matthias; Stolz, Stephan*, [**$\mathbf H\mathbf P^2$-bundles and elliptic homology**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02392533), Acta Math. 171, No. 2, 231-261 (1993). [ZBL0851.55007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0851.55007).

the $n$th elliptic homology group of a space $X$ is defined as
$$
\left.\bigoplus_{k\in\mathbb Z}\Omega_{n+8k}^{\mathrm{Spin}}(X)\right/\sim
$$
where $\sim$ identifies the class of $M\to X$ with the class of the composite $E\to M\to X$ where $E\to M$ is some $\mathbf{HP}^2$-bundle over a spin manifold $M$.

On the other hand, in

*Totaro, Burt*, [**Chern numbers for singular varieties and elliptic homology.**](https://doi.org/10.2307/121047), Ann. Math. (2) 151, No. 2, 757-791 (2000). [ZBL1050.14500](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1050.14500).

elliptic homology is obtained as complex bordism modulo identification of any two smooth projective varieties that are related by a classical flop. For convenience, let me sketch his definition. Varieties $X_1$ and $X_2$ are related by a classical flop if they are both IH-small resolutions of the same variety $Y$ that is Zariski locally a product of the 3-fold node and a smooth variety.

Totaro also has a version for $SU$-bordism modulo the ideal generated by manifolds which are (total spaces of?) twisted projective bundles $\widetilde{\mathbf{CP}}(A\oplus B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are rank 2 complex vector bundles over a weakly complex manifold $Z$ with $c_1(A)+c_1(B)+c_1(Z)=0$. He mentions that his results are analogous to the results of Kreck and Stolz but I do not see the connection clearly enough.

How precisely do these two definitions of elliptic homology relate? Is there a version of elliptic homology that would subsume both approaches?